# Get last record in every month - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my db i have stored price of products for everyday.

I need records based on last record of every month.

when i apply group by month, it is giving the first record of the month.

Query i have tried was,

```
select * from product where product_id = 52   
AND YEAR(date_modified) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY MONTH(date_modified)
```

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: post your `create table code` please.

Comment: Last record of a month means highest last_modified value comparing with the other records' last_modified value of that month ?

Comment: OR last record of a month means that record will have the highest primary key value comparing with other records' primary key value of that month?

Comment: [Standard greatest-n-per-group-problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group).  Your current query isn't actually getting the "first row for each month" - it's actually getting an **UNDEFINED** result row (could be _anything_), which happens to be the first of the month (likely due to probable indices).

Comment: Thanks guys for ur reply, I got solution by - select * from (select * from product ORDER BY date_modified DESC) as record where product_id = 52 and YEAR(date_modified) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY month(date_modified)

Comment: thanks for reply yar

Comment: `select 
* from 
(
select * from product 
WHERE product_id = 52
ORDER BY date_modified DESC
) as record 
WHERE YEAR(record.date_modified) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY month(record.date_modified)` it might give better performance comparing to the one stated above.

Comment: yeah correct yar. Just now our team was discussing about performance of the query, you replied finest query. superb move yar

Answer (score 2):

Have a derived table where you using `GROUP BY` find each product's latest date per month. Join with that derived table:

```
select * from
product t1
join (select product_id, max(date_modified) max_date_modified from product
      group by product_id, YEAR(date_modified), MONTH(date_modified)) t2
  on t1.product_id = t2.product_id and t1.date_modified = t2.max_date_modified
where product_id = 52
```

Comment: `product_id = 52` have to use inner in  `JOIN` select because it will be more faster